# How can you add Children to an ItemsPanelTemplate of an ItemsControl in WPF?

Tags: wpf, xaml, canvas, itemscontrol

I have the following ItemsControl:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ControllableLedList}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas Width="600" Height="600" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Background="FloralWhite" >
                <Ellipse Width="600" Height="600" Fill="#FF252525" /> <!-- big Ellipse causing my error -->
            </Canvas>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding PositionX}" />
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding PositionY}" />
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Ellipse  Width="5" Height="5" Fill="Yellow"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Basically the idea here is to have a canvas with a collection of ellipses (let's call them LEDs, since that what they represent in the real world), where the position of the LED ellipses is controlled from the `ViewModel`
The above code works well except for the big Ellipse in the Canvas -> as soon as I add it, I get the following Error:

> InvalidOperationException: Cannot explicitly modify Children collection of Panel used as ItemsPanel for ItemsControl. ItemsControl generates child elements for Panel

This makes sense, since the "actual children - the LED Ellipses" should be generated dynamically during runtime. Anyway, how can I get my big ellipse into my canvas, so that the order of visibility would be `Canvas.Background`->`Big Ellipse`-> `LED Ellipses`?

Comment: As a note, in order to draw centered circles, you may use a Path with an EllipseGeometry instead of an Ellipse in the ItemTemplate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may add the Ellipse to the Template of the ItemsControl:

```
<ItemsControl.Template>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ItemsControl">
        <Canvas>
            <Ellipse Width="600" Height="600" Fill="#FF252525" />
            <ItemsPresenter/>
        </Canvas>
    </ControlTemplate>
</ItemsControl.Template>
<ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <Canvas/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
```

Comment: Works perfectly fine. So one needs two canvas, or are they referencing each other?

Comment: The second is created in the place where ItemsPresenter is specified. And it is better to replace the first one with a regular Grid.

Comment: A Grid isn't better. The point is that there is another *suitable* Panel element in the ControlTemplate. Whether you nest Canvases or other Panels depends on your actual layout constraints. The ControlTemplate is also the place where you would typically put a ScrollViewer in case the ItemsControl needs to be scrollable.